# cauchy problem for semilinear PDE $xu_x+yu_y = 4u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am really stuck in the following problem

> consider the following semi linear **PDE**:
>   $$xu_x+yu_y = 4u$$
>   where $u(x,y)$ lies on unit circle given by $x^2+y^2$=1. Then find the value of $u(2,2)$.

Any help would be appericiated...

Comment: When you have a Cauchy problem, you are usually given a PDE and the values of an unknown function on a certain CURVE. What your curve, then?

Comment: What does it mean "$u(x,y)$ lies on unit circle"? Does it mean that $u=0$ on these points? If affirmative, $u$ is identically zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved by the method of characteristics.  Consider a curve $(x(t), y(t))$ where
$$\dot{x} = x$$
$$\dot{y} = y$$
By the multivariable chain rule,
$$D_t u = xu_x + yu_y = 4u$$
Thus,
$$u(x(t), y(t)) = u(x(0), y(0))e^{4t}$$
We can also solve for $x(t), y(t)$ to get
$$x(t) = x(0)e^t, \quad y(t) = y(0)e^t$$
so, assuming the initial data is given on the unit circle (I'll let you work out the details):
$$u(x,y) = u\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2.$$

Comment: How did you simplified $xu_x+yu_y = 4u$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses That comes from assuming $u$ satisfies the PDE $xu_x + yu_y = 4u$

Comment: and $u(2,2)=$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses Plug in $x = y = 2$.  I get $u(2,2) = 64u\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.